# Embedded Jetty responds to clear http on port 443

Tags: java, ssl, embedded-jetty, tls1.2

I have a Java 8 application using embedded Jetty 9.3.11 that wants to listen for https-only connections on a port (TCP/443). However, when a clear HTTP client connects the browser ends up downloading a small file of 7 bytes. Here is what od outputs for the file:

```
$ od -t x1 download
0000000 15 03 03 00 02 02 50
0000007
```

There is a requirement to not respond to clear text HTTP on TLS-only port 443. Interestingly, Jetty 9.1.3 does not behave this way.

My questions are the following:

1. What is this file and what other side-effects could be present for clear-text HTTP requests on my HTTPS-only port 443?
2. How can I stop Jetty from responding to clear HTTP this way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bytes are:

```
15 03 03 00 02 02 50
```

where:

```
15    == TLS Alert Message Type
03 03 == TLS Protocol version 1.2
00 02 == TLS Frame length
02    == Alert level Fatal
50    == Internal Error
```

Seems like a normal TLS response when it can't understand the non-TLS client.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know how I can disable this? I want the server to have no response to clear-HTTP clients.

Comment: Not possible ATM.  The Java SSL/TLS Stack is too complicated with the combination of TLS/1.2 + ALPN at the moment.  We hope that when Java 9 hits, with its built-in ALPN support, this will become possible.

Comment: Talking TLS over non-TLS is non-sensical. Not very different from starting a fax on a voice call. It seems the TLS stack has taken over all connections which it should not. Why is this traffic even involving the TLS stack?

Comment: Example: If you connect to a SMTP server and send something non SMTP, you get a SMTP response telling you that it doesn't understand you. (this is true for the vast majority of protocols).

Comment: Your ServerConnector is setup for SSL/TLS, hence the response.

Comment: TLS only SMTP port (i.e. 465) will not have any response to a non-TLS client. It just is forbidden to talk unless there is a TLS connection. Imagine the risk of saying something in a non-secure line, whoever is on the other side and whoever else is watching the line has more information now.

Comment: ServerConnectors set up for SSL/TLS should not respond in any way unless there is SSL/TLS. At the very least, there should be a way to change the "response".

Comment: The ServerConnector in this situation is responding using TLS.

Comment: With reference to "using TLS" in your comment above, there is no TLS when it starts talking.